# @Html.ValidationMessageFor for a bool in ASP.NET MVC 4

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, validation, razor

I am trying to create a drop down list or radio buttons for a a bool. Question: are you a public practicing attorney? yes/no. However, I need them to answer the question and not have it default to false if nothing is selected. Meaning on submit if they do not select yes or no they receive an error message telling them to answer the question. I am open to anything that will work. I am still a newbie so nothing to advanced please!

I have unsuccessfully tried html.dropdownlist, html.dropdownlistfor and

```
<select class="form-control" id="PublicPractice" name="PublicPractice">
<option value= null>--Select One--</option> 
<option value="True">Yes</option>
<option value="False">No</option>
</select>
```

Model

```
public bool PublicPractice { get; set; }
```

View

```
@Html.EditorFor(model => model.PublicPractice)
@Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.PublicPractice)
```

Answer (score 1):

Instead of declaring PublicPractice to be bool, use bool? that will allow a null value, then check for that null value in your code..

Answer (score 0):

One option is to not allow them to not select a value, and you can do that by setting the initial value of PublicPractice to false in the ViewModel's constructor.

```
public ViewModel()
{
    PublicPractice = false;
}
```

Then, call RadioButtonFor on the view:

```
@Html.RadioButtonFor(x => x.PublicPractice, true)
@Html.RadioButtonFor(x => x.PublicPractice, false)
```

Doing this forces them to either leave PublicPractice as false or change it to true, and won't allow them to not give an answer.

Answer (score 0):

This is what I did to make it work. I am sure that there is a better way, but this worked for me.

Model:

```
public bool? PublicPractice { get; set; }
```

Controller:

```
//check to see if they answered if they are public practice attorney
           string pp = Convert.ToString(collection["PublicPractice"]);
           if (pp == "noAnswer")
           {
               TempData["ClassSelected"] = cs;
               TempData["PPerror"] = "Sorry, but you did not answer...";
               return RedirectToAction("Register", "ClassList", new { id = cs });
           }
```

View:

```
@if (TempData["PPerror"] != null)
    {
        <h3 style="color:red">@TempData["PPerror"]</h3>
    }
```

more code here that does not apply.

```
<select class="form-control" id="PublicPractice" name="PublicPractice">
<option value= "noAnswer">--Select One--</option> 
<option value="True">Yes</option>
<option value="False">No</option>
</select>
```